# Django 3 by example bookmarklet_launcher.js

Tags: javascript, django

Following is a piece of code in the Django 3 by example book we can use to bookmark in a browser and upon clicking the bookmark, the code in it will be executed.
Can anyone please help me understand this code?

```
(function(){ if (window.myBookmarklet !== undefined){ myBookmarklet(); } else { document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('script')).src='https://127.0.0.1:8000/static/js/bookmarklet.js?r='+Math.floor(Math.random()*99999999999999999999); } })();
```

1. Why do we need to put the function inside parenthesis? (function.....)()
2. How the browser executes the code. We put a javascript tag at the start of the code.

    JavaScript:(function.....)()
3. what is this function myBookmarklet() and when if statement will be actually executed? How will the window object have myBookmarklet property?

Any relevant resources will be appreciated. Thanks a lot

Comment: function name (){} is just a function definition and (function(){})() is a function definition and auto-executable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. It's because it's an [anonymous function](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/JavaScript/Anonymous_functions), it has no name. Because it has no name and needs to be executed, it has to be surrounded with parenthesis to be able to run it by calling it with `()` at the end.
2. Exactly like that. If you want to write a function that will not be needed in any other place, you can define it without a name so it's anonymous. To call it, see 1.
3. Before that js code, the HTML file has probably a series of `<script>` tags where it defines certain dependencies, in this case javascript files. One of those js files has assigned `myBookmarklet` to `window`, like this: `window.myBookmarklet = //... a function definition`. The code you posted is checking if `window.myBookmarklet !== undefined` before calling that function.